# Split several columns by "space" pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split my data frame by "space" for all columns. I can do it for 1 column. How to apply it to the whole data? (maybe with loop)

```
df = 

    0      1      2      4  

11 22  12 22  13 22  14 22
15 16  17 18  33 44  22 55
19 20  21 22  66 55  33 66
23 24  25 26  22 44  66 44
```

I am splitting in like:

```
df[0].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

Output is:

```
0   1

11  22
15  16
19  20
23  24
```

Comment: for loop , the concat it back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `stack` and `unstack`:

```
df.stack().str.split(' ', expand=True).unstack()
```

Output:

```
    0               1            
    0   1   2   4   0   1   2   4
0  11  12  13  14  22  22  22  22
1  15  17  33  22  16  18  44  55
2  19  21  66  33  20  22  55  66
3  23  25  22  66  24  26  44  44
```

Comment: and then `df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)`